# How does one create global variables for MediaWiki articles?

Tags: mediawiki

I have created a website powered by MediaWiki that offers documentation on the interface for a web application.

The URL for my web application may change. However, many articles on this MediaWiki site link to the application.

I would like to create a global constant somewhere called say "WEB_APP_URL" that I may change at any time, and that editors of the wiki can use to link to the application.

That way, I won't have to do a massive find and replace when my application URL changes.

Is this possible? I am working in a LAMP environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to create a [template](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates). That is, you can create a page called `Template:web-app URL` with this wiki-text:

```
http://this.is/the/URL/of/the/web.app
```

and then editors can write things like:

```
The application is located at {{web-app URL}}.
```

or:

```
[{{web-app URL}} David Faux's application]
```

and the URL will automatically get dropped in.

(That's not the only way — you can get similar effects through internal configurations and hooks — but I think the template-based approach is the simplest.)

Comment: Thanks! That was really straightforward to use.