# site wide (global) variables on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

Folks,

I'd like to have similar set up to the one discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840717/how-does-one-create-global-variables-for-mediawiki-articles) question

Can I use templates to form a set of variables that I can then later include in various points in my wiki pages.

so for example have varables in my single template called `MAIN_WEB_URL` and `MAIN_TEAM_DISTRIBUTION_LIST` that I can store in a single template and reference site-wide where needed.

I'd like to avoid a template per variable if possible, but the other question seems to imply this is the only way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a template called something like `Template:Variable`. In it, you would use one big `{{#switch}}` that would contain the variables and their values (this requires [the ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aParserFunctions#.23switch)):

```
{{#switch: {{{1}}}
| MAIN_WEB_URL = some value
| MAIN_TEAM_DISTRIBUTION_LIST = another value
}}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
{{variable|MAIN_WEB_URL}}
```

(BTW, I am not a fan of ALL_CAPS names and I think there is no reason to use them here, but that's up to you.)